# Jsp is not getting compiled by Jersey within a spring boot app

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

I am trying to setup a spring boot app with Jersey.
The Rest API is working fine however the view (jsp) is getting rendered as is as plain text on browser.
I tried including jstl in my dependencies , once I include it ; server starts returning blank response.

Please let me know what am I missing here .

Code Structure:

[image]

Below is my code:

**JerseyConfig.java**

```
package com.example.jersey.configuration;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.jersey.controller.HelloController;
import com.example.jersey.controller.HelloJSPController;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/jersey")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    public JerseyConfig()
    {
        property(JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/jsp");
        register(JspMvcFeature.class);
        register(HelloController.class);
        register(HelloJSPController.class);

    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.example.jersey.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello Jersey with Spring boot";
    }
}
```

**HelloJSPController**

```
package com.example.jersey.controller;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Singleton
@Path("/helloJSP")
public class HelloJSPController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable getIt(@Context final ServletContext context) {

        return new Viewable("/index");
    }
}
```

**SpringJerseyApplication.java**

```
package com.example.jersey;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJerseyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJerseyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jersey.servlet.load-on-startup=1
spring.jersey.type=filter
logging.level.root=INFO
```

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello Jsp .</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello JSP
  </body>

  </html>
```

**EDIT:**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-jersey</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->


        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below is the response I get when I try to access JSP
[image]

If I uncomment tomcat-embed-jasper, my application doesn't comes up.
It throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1186) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the spring boot version to 1.5.12 makes the JSP working for me.
Something is probably broken with spring boot 2.0.1
Below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-jersey</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```